# display image and text in same line - 2 colums unordered list

Tags: html, css, frontend

I asked this question yesterday and got a solution. It turns out that, I am supposed to use a different approach (work place necessity).

I have a 2 column unordered list. I want the text to be spaced little away from the image ( I have thsi working) and 2nd  of text align with the first line. I am not able to get this.

```
<section class="freedom_carousel"> 

<ul class="two-col-special">
<li> <p class="item"> <img class="icon" src="/pth/to/image" > <span class="icon-text"> <b>This is </b> TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT </span> </p></li>
<li> <p class="item"> <img class="icon" src="/pth/to/image" > <span class="icon-text"> <b>This is </b> TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT </span> </p></li>
<li> <p class="item"> <img class="icon" src="/pth/to/image" > <span class="icon-text"> <b>This is </b> TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT </span> </p></li>
<li> <p class="item"> <img class="icon" src="/pth/to/image" > <span class="icon-text"> <b>This is </b> TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT </span> </p></li>
</ul>

   </section>
```

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jx6nwr62/1/

I believe its something to do with the display:block. I have been trying various combinations and nothing seem to work right.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You mean [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/jx6nwr62/2/)?

Comment: Yes, that works perfectly. Thank you very much. 

But, turns out I need to trim the code down much more. I am trying out this. http://jsfiddle.net/rwcbdk38/. What am I missing?